# anyone can explain how does this code send message to specified user

Tags: websocket, spring-webflux

```
@Bean
public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler() {
    TopicProcessor<String> messageProcessor = this.messageProcessor();
    Flux<String> messages = messageProcessor.replay(0).autoConnect();
    Flux<String> outputMessages = Flux.from(messages);

    return (session) -> {
        System.out.println(session);

        session.receive().map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText).subscribe(messageProcessor::onNext, (e) -> {
            e.printStackTrace();
        });

        return session.getHandshakeInfo().getPrincipal().flatMap((p) -> {
            session.getAttributes().put("username", p.getName());
            return session.send(outputMessages.filter((payload) -> this.filterUser(session, payload))
                    .map((payload) -> this.generateMessage(session, payload)));
        }).switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
            return Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials."));
        })).then();
    };
}
```

I am trying to build a online chating system with webflux,and have found a example through github.as a beginner in reactor development,I am confused about how does this code send a message to single user.

### this is the way i think of in springmvc

1. put all the active websocketsession into map
2. check every message if the field username in message equals the username stored in session,use this session send msg

   private static Map clients = new ConcurrentHashMap();
     public void sendMessageTo(String message, String ToUserName) throws IOException {

   ```
       for (WebSocket item : clients.values()) {
           if (item.username.equals(ToUserName) ) {
               item.session.sendText(message);
               break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

### can you explain how does the code in the webflux code above works?

i know all the messages are stored in the outputMessages and subcribed.
 when a new message be emitted,how does it find the correct session ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `WebSocketHandler` is an interface containing only one method `handle` [WebSocketHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketHandler.html)

which in turn i believe makes it a `FunctionalInterface` that can be used as a lambda.

```
(session) -> { ... }
```

So when a session is established with a client, and the client sends a websocket event. The server will look for the WebSocketHandler and populate it with the session from the client that sent the event.

If you find this confusing you can just implement the interface.

```
class ExampleHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {

            Mono<Void> input = session.receive()
                    .doOnNext(message -> {
                            // ...
                    })
                    .concatMap(message -> {
                            // ...
                    })
                    .then();

            Flux<String> source = ... ;
            Mono<Void> output = session.send(source.map(session::textMessage));

            return Mono.zip(input, output).then();
    }
}

@Bean
public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler() {
    return new ExampleHandler();
}
```